# Cisco APIC: How to get Date and Time Policy via CLI?

Tags: cisco

To get `Date and Time` Policy via GUI:

```
FABRIC > FABRIC POLICIES > Pod Policies > Expand Policies > Date and Time
```

[image]

Reference:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/cloud-systems-management/application-policy-infrastructure-controller-apic/200128-Configuring-NTP-in-ACI-Fabric-Solution.html

I've tried the following command, but none of them shows the policy name.

```
fabric1-leaf1# show ntp peers
--------------------------------------------------
  Peer IP Address               Serv/Peer
--------------------------------------------------
  173.36.129.235                Server (configured)





fabric1-leaf1# show ntp peer-status
Total peers : 1
* - selected for sync, + - peer mode(active),
- - peer mode(passive), = - polled in client mode
    remote                local                st   poll   reach delay   vrf
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*173.36.129.235          0.0.0.0               3    16     37    0.00134 management





fabric1-leaf1# show ntp statistics peer ipaddr 173.36.129.235
remote host:          173.36.129.235
local interface:      Unresolved
time last received:   2s
time until next send: 14s
reachability change:  408s
packets sent:         30
packets received:     30
bad authentication:   0
bogus origin:         0
duplicate:            0
bad dispersion:       0
bad reference time:   0
candidate order:      6
fabric1-leaf1#
```

Please let me know the right command to get Date and Time Policy via CLI/SSH. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these from APIC CLI:

```
APIC# moquery -c datetimePol
APIC# moquery -c datetimePol -x 'query-target=children'
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any good documentation about this?

Comment: In ACI all configuration is stored in MIT (Management Information Tree) as MO (Model Objects). Please read [this](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/aci/apic/sw/policy-model-guide/b-Cisco-ACI-Policy-Model-Guide.html) document to get more familiar with it. When you will get all idea about MIT and tools like Visore and Object Browser it will become easier for you to obtain data programmaticaly or via CLI.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, appreciate that. ACI is a new things for me.